# Ansible can we use if condition at hosts

Tags: ansible, devops

How to run the playbook on a specific set of hosts with a conditional variable

**vars_file.yml**

```yaml
deployment: blue
```

**hosts_file.yml**

```
[east1]
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2

[west2]
127.0.0.3
127.0.0.4
```

**playbook.yml**

```yaml
---
hosts: all
vars_files:
  - 'vars_file.yml'
tasks:
  - copy: src=config dest=/tmp/

hosts: {{ east1[0] if deployment == "blue" else west2[0]}}
vars_files:
  - 'vars_file.yml'
tasks:
  - shell: "./startup_script restart"
```

Note: I cant pass variables through the command line and I cant segregate task to a new playbook.

Comment: `ansible-(playbook)` has a `--limit | -l` option. Simply set in your play `hosts: dev` then call your playbook as `ansible-playbook -i your_inventory.ini your_playbook.yml -l dev[0]`

Comment: Updated question with a few more details, and in my case I need to run the playbook on all hosts because the playbook has other tasks which run on both groups.

Comment: Mhm, honestly, that really seems a different question than what it was at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access variables defined on another host by targeting the [`hostvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) dictionary key of that host.
In order to do that though, you need to register the variable on the host, with [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html), importing it won't be enough.

Here is an example, given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    east1:
      hosts:
        east_node_1:
          ansible_host: node1
        east_node_2:
          ansible_host: node4
    west2:
      hosts:
        west_node_1:
          ansible_host: node2
        west_node_2:
          ansible_host: node3
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vars_file.yml

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        deployment: "{{ deployment }}"

- hosts: >-
    {{ groups['east1'][0] 
         if hostvars['localhost'].deployment == 'blue' 
         else groups['west2'][0] 
    }}
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
```

This would yield the recaps:

- ```
  PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY [east_node_1] *****************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [east_node_1] => {
      "msg": "Hello world!"
  }

  PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
  east_node_1                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

  when *vars_file.yml* contains

  ```yaml
  deployment: blue
  ```
- And

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY [west_node_1] *****************************************************************************************************************

  TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************
  ok: [west_node_1] => {
      "msg": "Hello world!"
  }

  PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
  west_node_1                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

  when *vars_file.yml* contains

  ```yaml
  deployment: red
  ```

---

Another equivalent construction, using [patterns to target the group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-group-position-in-patterns), would just see the host target changed to:

```yaml
- hosts: >-
    {{ 'east1[0]' 
         if hostvars['localhost'].deployment == 'blue' 
         else 'west2[0]' 
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have been trying with ```east1[0]``` where it's throwing east1 is undefined error. Its working with ```groups['east1'][0]```. groups[] is the key one here.

Comment: Well it could also work with `east1[0]`, thanks to the [host patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-group-position-in-patterns). But then it should be a **string**. See updated answer

Comment: Yes, it worked with ```'east1[0]'```. Quotations ```' '``` was the problem.